Nginx laravel + vue on one domain
I need combine laravel admin panel and vue frontend in one domain. Frontend worked, but backend return 403 forbidden. All folder have chmod 755;
Nginx conf
server {

        server_name {domain};

        location / {
                alias /var/www/{name}/source-code/frontend/.output/public/;
                index index.html;
                location ~* \.(?:css|js|jpg|svg)$ {
                        expires 30d;
                        add_header Cache-Control "public";
                }

                location ~* \.(?:json)$ {
                        expires 1d;
                        add_header Cache-Control "public";
                }
        }

        location  /admin {
             alias /var/www/{name}/public;
             index index.php;
             try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;

             location ~ \.php$ {
                     include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                     fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.3-fpm.sock;
                 }
        }
}

i expect /admin/* could open
